# Could not find "store" in either the context or props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this error :

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the
>   context or props of "Connect(ItemIndex)". Either wrap the root
>   component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(ItemIndex)".

My code is :

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  promise
)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(<ItemIndex />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I forgot to add the provider

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <ItemIndex />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: With this approach can you test the `state` of `ItemIndex ` ? Had a similar approach but the I couldn't test the `state`.